# How to set a value as 1st row in a column, then continue in ASC in Tableau

Tags: sql-server, tableau-desktop

I have the following query that is able to do what I want in SQL Server but when I load it into Tableau I get an error :

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The ORDER BY
> clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables,
> subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR
> XML is also specified.

How do I fix this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT DW_RentHistory.[DW_RentHistoryID] AS id
          ,DW_RentHistory.[propertyID]
          ,bi_property.[name]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[state]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[metro]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[submarket]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[bed]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[bath]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[sqft]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[MONTH] AS month
          ,DW_RentHistory.[YEAR] AS year
          ,DW_RentHistory.[numUnits]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[effectiveRent] AS 'avgEffectiveRent'
          ,DW_RentHistory.[effectiveRentPerSqft] AS 'avgEffectiveRentPerSqft'
          ,DW_RentHistory.[mm_yyyy]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[date]
          ,DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, 1) AS 'Period'
          ,CASE WHEN bi_property.[name] = 'Market Average' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS sort_order
      FROM [texas].[dbo].[DW_RentHistory] INNER JOIN bi_property ON
         bi_property.propertyID = DW_RentHistory.propertyID
      WHERE DW_RentHistory.propertyID IN (
        SELECT propertyID FROM listItem WHERE selected = 1 AND listID = 921828
      ) AND DW_RentHistory.Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -14, GETDATE())
      AND (bi_property.preLeasing = 1 OR bi_property.completed = 1) AND (bi_property.inactive = 0)
    UNION
    SELECT
        0 as id
        ,0 as propert_id
        ,'Market Average' as name
        ,[state]
        ,[metro]
       ,'' as submarket
       ,0 as bed
       ,0 as bath
       ,0 as sqft
       ,[month]
       ,[year]
       ,[numUnits]
       ,[avgEffectiveRent]
       ,[avgEffectiveRentPerSqft]
       ,[date]
       ,[date]
       , DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, 1) AS 'Period'
       ,1 as sort_order
     FROM [dbo].[bi_floorplan_history_metro]
     WHERE metro IN (
        SELECT TOP 1 metro FROM bi_property WHERE propertyid IN (
          SELECT propertyID FROM listItem WHERE selected = 1 AND listID = 921828
        )
     ) AND date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -14, GETDATE())
) AS Subquery
ORDER BY sort_order, [name] ASC;
```

Comment: So it works without issue if you remove the ORDER BY? Is this a view?

Comment: Yup, removing the order by works fine, but adding it causes this error.

Comment: If your query works as is in management studio it probably means that tableau wraps your query in a subquery itself, but then, there should be a way of specifying sort in tableau itself

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering in Tableau is due to the fact that you're using an ORDER BY clause in a subquery without using a TOP, OFFSET, or FOR XML clause. While this is allowed in SQL Server.

To achieve your desired outcome without encountering this error, you can modify your query by removing the ORDER BY clause from the subquery and applying it only to the outer query. Here's how you can modify your query to work in Tableau:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT DW_RentHistory.[DW_RentHistoryID] AS id
          ,DW_RentHistory.[propertyID]
          ,bi_property.[name]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[state]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[metro]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[submarket]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[bed]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[bath]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[sqft]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[MONTH] AS month
          ,DW_RentHistory.[YEAR] AS year
          ,DW_RentHistory.[numUnits]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[effectiveRent] AS 'avgEffectiveRent'
          ,DW_RentHistory.[effectiveRentPerSqft] AS 'avgEffectiveRentPerSqft'
          ,DW_RentHistory.[mm_yyyy]
          ,DW_RentHistory.[date]
          ,DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, 1) AS 'Period'
          ,CASE WHEN bi_property.[name] = 'Market Average' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS sort_order
      FROM [texas].[dbo].[DW_RentHistory] INNER JOIN bi_property ON
         bi_property.propertyID = DW_RentHistory.propertyID
      WHERE DW_RentHistory.propertyID IN (
        SELECT propertyID FROM listItem WHERE selected = 1 AND listID = 921828
      ) AND DW_RentHistory.Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -14, GETDATE())
      AND (bi_property.preLeasing = 1 OR bi_property.completed = 1) AND (bi_property.inactive = 0)
    UNION
    SELECT
        0 as id
        ,0 as propert_id
        ,'Market Average' as name
        ,[state]
        ,[metro]
       ,'' as submarket
       ,0 as bed
       ,0 as bath
       ,0 as sqft
       ,[month]
       ,[year]
       ,[numUnits]
       ,[avgEffectiveRent]
       ,[avgEffectiveRentPerSqft]
       ,[date]
       ,[date]
       , DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, 1) AS 'Period'
       ,1 as sort_order
     FROM [dbo].[bi_floorplan_history_metro]
     WHERE metro IN (
        SELECT TOP 1 metro FROM bi_property WHERE propertyid IN (
          SELECT propertyID FROM listItem WHERE selected = 1 AND listID = 921828
        )
     ) AND date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -14, GETDATE())
) AS Subquery
ORDER BY sort_order, [name] ASC;
```

By removing the ORDER BY clause from the subquery and applying it only to the outer query, you should be able to avoid the error you were encountering in Tableau.

Comment: There is usually no value in using an order by clause in a custom sql query from Tableau, since Tableau will sort the query result as you specify on the client end -- so all the order by clause does is slow down the query.